# Getting an error "Bad Value" when HTML form from email is submitted

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am getting an error **Bad Value (line 47, file "scriptName", project "projectName")** when running the script from [Send form by email and track responses in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668828/send-form-by-email-and-track-responses-in-spreadsheet/18669532#18669532). I followed all the instructions but can't get it to work. I've also changed the **var _spreadsheetId = 'spreadsheetID';** to **var_spreadsheetID = '1gEdXyh-xT006vTaDAgxM-2eF_6F0QjKdypp245GvkxE';** but still getting the error. The ID was from the URL after the "*/d/*" and before the "*/edit...*"

Btw, I am a beginner in using JScript but I can follow. I just can't debug this one. I appreciate your response. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the errors for us to look at and a sample of your code if possible

Comment: Open-ended "How to" questions are difficult to answer, and tend to generate follow-up comment discussions. To improve your chances of getting a helpful answer, [edit] your question to provide greater focus on the specific problem you're facing. You should show what error messages you receive, and explain how you're running the code when you see them. See [ask].

Comment: @DavidAnderton This is the error for when I submit the form in the email. "Bad value (line 47, file "Code", project "Control Framework Monitoring")".
Edit: I'll review again the code. I just arrived from the office. I think I can solve this one. Will keep you posted though once I get through this thing. Thanks!

Comment: @Mogsdad I'll revise the question later. I think I can give it a try again.

Comment: @zouchii sounds like on line 47 you are sending a value that is different from what you expect and that is causing the error. Check the line number and most likely your problem will be nearby.

Comment: @DavidAnderton sorry for the late update, i have fixed it now I have another one, well bugs after bugs. Thanks btw!

Comment: @Zouchii if you can answer your own question here that would be awesome - perhaps someone else will run into the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I followed the instructions in the [Send form by email and track responses in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668828/send-form-by-email-and-track-responses-in-spreadsheet/18669532#18669532). In the declaration of the variable for spreadsheetID: **var _spreadsheetId = '--- Spreadsheet ID ---';** instead of using **'** *(apostrophe)*, use **"** *(quotation marks)* on both ends.

Comment: this is not correct. in javascript you can use ' or " for strings (unless the string already contains ' but yours doesn't)