# Is it possible to email a form

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

I want to email a form to customers to fill out in the browser or ideally in rheir email client . I have created a form opened it by id , then sent it using

```
function openDialog() {

  // Open a form by ID.
  var form = FormApp.openById('kdhgsdfskfhs');


  var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response).getContent();
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'me@gmail.com',
    subject: 'hi',
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  });

}
```

You can see the result which I have put in screenshot . I'm starting to think that this is not doable in apps script. Is it possible ? if not what is the best way to send allow a user to enter info into a spreadsheet?

Comment: Is it ok to just send the link to the form. That way the user can open the link from email, fill the form, which in-turn fills the spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm not opposed to that. How would you generate the link and is there a way to track who you sent the link to?

Comment: `htmlBody=url` should work in the above. I'm not sure of `how to know whom you sent`, but you can make the form return back the identity of the person once he opens and accepts conditions. Which would then be displayed back in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible email html.  But I think your going to need a website or a webapp or a link to the online form to submit it to a spreadsheet.